# Graphics and fn keys problem with Lenovo and Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, graphics, lenovo, brightness

I set up a dual boot with Ubuntu. But my laptop model is not quite supported within Linux. I have a serious problem with graphics, I don't have a control over the graphics, I can't control the brightness (which affects my eyes pretty bad), my fn keys aren't working as well. I wasn't able to fix it with advices I have came across online.

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Creator 5 - 15IMH05 which has drivers for Windows only.

My best guess is that the problem occurs due to the fact that I have 2 GPUs. One is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti. The second one is Intel UHD Graphics (integrated). Maybe I am missing some important part of the setup?

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: The [Fn] key operates independent of any OS, so it's weird that you're having issues with it. As for the video devices, let's examine some hardware. Can you update your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -C video` and also `lspci`? This will make it more likely that solutions can be offered 